# Nginx reverse proxy: How to serve 'back soon' html file while backend server restarts

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, failover, error-handling

I have a WSGI server behind by nginx. Say I bring the WSGI instance down for maintenance/update, is there a nice way of nginx automatically serving up any requests to that application with a specified HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static page `/50x.html` with your desired content, and then add something like this to your nginx configuration:

```
error_page 502 503 504 /50x.html;
```

The [error_page](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) directive is used to override nginx's internal error pages.